# como llenar un jcombobox en java?

Tags: java, mysql

quiero llenar mi jcombobox desde mi base de datos , pero solo se llena el primer registro y no todos los demas,debe cargarse ni bien se abre el jframe form

aca inicializo mi metodo para llenar el combobox

```
public class adm_pedidos extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    /**
     * Creates new form adm_pedidos
     */

    Connection cn = null;
    Statement stm = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = null;

    public adm_pedidos() {
        initComponents();
        mostrarpedidos();
        llenar_combo_actividad();
        llenar_combo_usuarios();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
    }
```

Y este es el metodo:

```
private void llenar_combo_actividad() {        
    try {
        sql="select distinct(codigo_actividad),descripcion from activida_gasto";
        cn = accesodb.getConnection();
        stm= cn.createStatement();
        rs=stm.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            cbxactividad.addItem(rs.getString(2));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, e);
    }
}
```

Como ven hay un system.out.print.ln para ver cual es la consulta y me sale correcta es decir si lo pongo en el mysql me sale todos los registros, cuando hice el debug solo entra una vez en el rs.next() y por eso solo registra el primero, pero nose por que  solo entra una vez, si supuestamente son varios registros 
espero su ayuda gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que tu **ResultSet** se está cargando con un sólo registro, justamente aquí:

```
 rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
```

Intenta agregándole **.getResultSet** para que obtengas todo el conjunto de resultados de la sentencia y no solo la primera línea, así:

```
 rs = stm.executeQuery(sql).getResultSet();
```

Espero te haya servido mi respuesta, saludos.